# Proving limit properties

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

From [Trench Real Analysis](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_REAL_ANALYSIS.PDF)

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

1. What if $\epsilon \ge 1$? How does the proof not hold?
2. How do we have $|g(x)| > \frac{|L_2|}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1.** If you have a $\delta$ corresponding to some $\varepsilon < 1$, then take the same $\delta$ for any $\varepsilon \geqslant 1$. This can simply be seen by choosing $\varepsilon < 1$ and $\eta \geqslant 1$. If $$\left| f(x) - L\right| < \varepsilon$$ whenever $0 < \left| x - x_0\right| < \delta$, then for sure for the same $\delta > 0$ $$\left| f(x) - L\right| < \varepsilon < \eta$$

**Part 2.** We have $$\left|\left| g(x)\right| - \left|L_2 \right|\right| \leqslant \left| g(x) - L_2 \right| < \frac{\left| L_2\right|}{2}$$ by the reversed triangle inequality and thus $$-\frac{\left| L_2\right|}{2}< \left| g(x)\right| - \left|L_2 \right| < \frac{\left| L_2\right|}{2}$$ Hence by the left side inequality $$-\frac{\left| L_2\right|}{2}< \left| g(x)\right| - \left|L_2 \right| \Leftrightarrow \frac{\left| L_2\right|}{2}< \left| g(x)\right|$$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. How does the proof not hold if $\epsilon \ge 1$?

Comment: @BCLC Because then you cannot do the estimate $\left( \varepsilon + |L_1| + |L_2|\right) \varepsilon \leqslant \left( 1 + |L_1| + |L_2|\right) \varepsilon$. It would work also, but if you restrict yourself to $\varepsilon < 1$, it is more clear, that the upper bound can be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: Oh that's strange. I missed that. Thanks TheGeekGreek! ^-^

Answer (score 0):

1. Who cares? When doing analysis, you usually consider $\epsilon>0$ a "small enough" parameter, so you are not interested in knowing what happens if $\epsilon$ is bigger than something.
2. Go on reading the proof. You have cut out the explanation from your post.

Comment: To add to this, the reason that we can ignore $\epsilon\ge 1$ is that if we prove the result for $\epsilon = 1/2$, say, then we have that $\vert f(x)-L\vert$ is less than $1/2$, and hence is also less than any $\epsilon\ge1$. The  reason *why* we would do this is because assuming $\epsilon$ to be small tends to simplify the algebra.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. How does the proof not hold if $\epsilon \ge 1$? @πr8

Comment: It's necessary in order to bound the $(\epsilon + L_1 + L_2)$ term from above by $(1+ L_1 + L_2)$ (line 6 to 7)

Comment: @πr8 Oh that's strange. I missed that. Thanks! Do we have to do that though?

Comment: It's less that we *have* to, and more that it simplifies the proof to make this assumption. The idea is basically to get the inequality down to something of the form $\vert  fg-L_1 L_2 \vert \le(\text{ some constant })\cdot\epsilon$, and bounding $\epsilon$ above facilitates that handily here.

Comment: @πr8 Thanks! ^-^